# Can no longer run compiled programs on cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, bash, cygwin

An odd problem has recently developed with cygwin. If I try to compile a simple C++ program like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
   cout << "hello world." << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

it compiles without errors. When I try to run it from the cygwin terminal, it hangs and produces no messages. I can kill the cygwin terminal and bash, but taskmanager will not kill hello.exe. I googled a bit but didn't find much that was relevant. I updated cygwin.

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 0ev5 2.4.0(0.291/5/3) 2015-11-10 10:21 x86_64 Cygwin
```

but that was no help. Cygwin is running on Windows 7. As far as I know, I hadn't made any changes to the system before the problem arose.

Any clues would be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: Do you have avast running?  There has been a lot of issues lately related to antivirus causing the terminal to not run/be blank.

Comment: Avast was the culprit. This is a laptop from my university and I had forgotten that Avast was running.  Thanks!